# Orthogonal Basis for Partial Differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Does taking partial dervatives in $\mathbb{R}^n$ acutally requrire us to take an orthogonal basis? I know the partial derivative as directional derivative in the direction of a basis vector, but nothing about that seems to use a dot product. A bunch of authors seem to require it, but is there something that goes wrong (other than we can't draw pretty pictures anymore) if we take an arbitrary basis?

Comment: The partials are with respect to the standard basis $e_1, e_2,...$. That is, ${ \partial f(x) \over \partial x_k} = \lim_{t \to 0} {f(x+t e_k)-f(x) \over t}$. You can take the direction derivative in whatever direction you want.

Comment: When people say standard basis do they mean the basis vectors are orthogonal? This is what I've always assumed.

Comment: $x$ has the form $(x_1,x_2,...)$, and the basis vectors are $e_1= (1,0,0,...)$, $e_2 = (0,1,0,...)$, etc.

Comment: Any ordered set of vector you take will have $e_1=(1,0,0,...,0)$ and so on. This doens't tell me if the basis you're taking is orthogonal or not

Comment: Yes, and the function will be defined in terms of $f( \sum_k x_k e_k)$, so when you take the partials, it will be with respect to this $x_k$. You are given a function $f(x_1,x_2,...)$, how the $x_k$ translate into some space is sort of irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry this is confusing me more than clarifying. Are you basis vectors $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ orthogonal or not? I understand taking partials are taking directional derivatives in coordinate directions. I'm not clear on what your second sentence is saying though.

Comment: When you write $f(x_1,x_2,...)$ then you can compute partial derivatives with respect to the $x_k$. There is no need for a basis, or inner product.

Comment: If you pick another basis $b_k$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define a map $L(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_k x_k b_k$ then the function $(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto f(L(x_1,...,x_n))$ is a different (but obviously related) function and the partials will be different, in general.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this some thought